# How to read an entire folder from Resources - Java 8 Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

I have a Spring Boot project with Java 8.

My project has a requirement to add certificates to Java Keystore due to some peculiarities.

I have created a folder inside resource folders where I'll put all the certificates:

[image]

My spring boot application is compiled in a .jar file.

I'm trying to read the whole `client_cert` folder, so I'll be able to iterate over each file in it.

But are hard to make out how to do it.

This is how I'm currently doing this:

```java
package my.app.config;

/**imports*/

@Configuration
public class ClientSSLConfig {

    @Bean
    public void getCertificates(){
        try{
            
            File folder = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/client_cert").toURI());

            for(File file : folder.listFiles()){
                loadCerts(file);
            }

        } catch ( URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

.....
```

This is not working.

It Throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`.

If I try different, using `getFile()` instead of `toURI()`, it kinda works, but the `listFiles()` returns null:

[image]

I tried to use `getResourceAsStream()` but I end up stuck in the same problem.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: What's not working? You can't find any file in the folder? Is it working locally but not when packaged? Do you get an error? In addition, I don't think you can get a Bean from a void method. I never checked because it makes no sense. If you want something to run at startup, check CommandLineRunner

Comment: @grekier question eddited and errors added. In addition, I'm using `@Bean` just to get the method executed on the startup, I'll change it to `@PostConstruct` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use a `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` (resolver)
- filter out all *.cert* files via `resolver.getResources("client_cert/*.cert")`

This will load all the certificates at startup

```java
@Component
class ClientCertComponent {

    @EventListener
    public void loadCerts(ApplicationReadyEvent event) throws IOException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] clientCerts = resolver.getResources("client_cert/*.cert");
        for (Resource cert:clientCerts){
            loadCert(cert);
        }
    }

    public void loadCert(Resource cert){
        // load the client certificate
    }

}
```

Comment: The `ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:client_cert").toPath()` throws `class path resource [client_cert] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/client_cert` :(

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to read a file from a folder named properties in /resources. tweak to return the proper format.
Look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html for usage of PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver. It can return back multiple files also. (In my case I just needed one.)

```
/**
 * In Spring this will read a file from src/main/resources/properties folder
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String readFileInProperties(String fileName) throws Exception
{
    String retData = null;
    try {
        // Get all the files under this inner resource folder: properties
        String scannedPackage = "properties/" + fileName;;
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver scanner = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] resources = scanner.getResources(scannedPackage);

        if (resources == null || resources.length == 0)
        {
            log.warn("Warning: could not find any resources in this scanned package: " + scannedPackage);
        }
        else 
        {
            if(resources.length != 1)
            {
                log.error("More than one file : " + scannedPackage);
                throw new RuntimeException("More than one file : " + scannedPackage);
            }
            for (Resource resource : resources) 
            {
                log.info(resource.getFilename());
                try(InputStream is = resource.getInputStream())
                {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int nRead;
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) 
                    {
                        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
                    }

                    buffer.flush();
                    byte[] byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();
                    retData = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to read the resources folder: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return retData;
}
```

Comment: Got similar error :(. `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [client_cert] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/client_cert` I

Comment: @VitorNilson 1) Unpack your jar file (Rename it to zip and look at it.) Find out where your file is. 2) The code I specified looks for a file in the /src/main/resources/properties folder. for a file and returns it as a String. You will need to change my example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewrite your code as

```java
@Configuration
public class ClientSSLConfig {
    @Value("classpath:/client_cert")
    private Resource resource;
    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Bean
    public void getCertificates(){
        try{
            // Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/client_cert", YourSpringBootApplication.class);
            // Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("/client_cert");
            File folder = resource.getFile();

            for(File file : folder.listFiles()){
                loadCerts(file);
            }

        } catch ( URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This example throws me `class path resource [client_cert] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/client_cert` :/

Comment: Updated. Try passing class of your Spring Boot application as the 2nd parameter. Alternatively you can use `@Value`

Comment: Same error :/. I tried both ClientSSLConfig.class and MainSpringBoot.class and got the same error.

Comment: And what about `@Value` or `ResourceLoader`?